# Xcode: Swift - How to save drag and drop tableview cell positions (core data)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Im quite new to swift development. I need some **help with saving the positions of the cells** after drag and drop the cells. The thing is I can drag and drop the cells without any problem. However, the **cells resets to the old position** when I navigate to other view controllers or when I close and open back the simulator.

I followed the another stackoverflow answers to do this but I can't find any answer relevant to my question.I have posted the codes I used to do drag and drop function. Would appreciate the help, thanks.

```
var notes = [Notes]()
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    tableview.dragDelegate = self
    tableview.dropDelegate = self
    tableview.dragInteractionEnabled = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
    loadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
    dragItem.localObject = notes[indexPath.row]
    return [ dragItem ]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mover = notes.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    notes.insert(mover, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    
    
    tableview.reloadData()

}
```

---

Update 1 : I tried this but it did not work

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: 
 IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mover = notes.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    notes.insert(mover, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    do{
                try notes.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("Rows could not be saved")
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw there is a `loadData()` method, but can't see what it actual does.

I guess if the `loadData()` method load your data from Core Data and store to the `notes` array? If so, then it should be the problem. Since you modified the `notes`(by calling `notes.remove()` and `notes.insert()`), but you has not save `notes` to Core Data, so after `loadData()` in `viewVillAppear` be called, you load the origin data from Core Data to `notes` again.

To fix it, you should save `notes` to Core Data just after `notes.insert()`.